# How to reference html form element values in tsc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

How do I tell tsc to not complain about accessing form field values?

I'm trying to use the Typescript compiler, tsc, to validate some Javascript (not Typescript). In general, it works pretty well, but it's giving me false positives for any references to form fields.

For example, if I access a text input with:

```
let value = document.querySelector('#myinput').value;
```

then tsc complains with:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

Is there a way to either disable this specific check (but not all property checks), or reference the input value in a way that works in both Typescript and Javascript?

I can't use a type casting like:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(elementId)).value;
```

or:

```
(document.getElementById(elementId) as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

because that breaks Javascript and all the tools I use to validate/minify/bundle my Javascript files.

Substituting `.value` with `.textContent` doesn't functionally seem to do that same thing and doesn't actually retrieve the text input's value.

Comment: "*I'm trying to use the Typescript compiler, tsc, to validate some Javascript (not Typescript).*" - why don't you write Typescript? I don't think there's a way to validate JS (maybe `.d.ts` files?).

Comment: have you tried annotating your variable with a JSDoc `@type` comment?

Comment: @DanO That might work, but requires introducing a temporary variable for the element

Comment: What is the rationale for using `tsc` to validate your JavaScript files?